# HTML: Change the font size of the Blogger Post Title

Tags: html, css, blogger

I tried a new theme for my blogger (http://alstat.blogspot.com/). Everything was fine, except for the post title. When I'm in the home page of my blog I got this **large text post title**, but when I click on one of my post, the post title font changes and the size of it becomes **small**. The theme is actually available here (http://btemplates.com/2010/blogger-template-heliumified/). I played around the css code, and tried to edit the following. I tried changing the `.post h3 a,.post h3 a:visited,.post h3 strong` to `.post h2 a,.post h2 a:visited,.post h2 strong`, and this .`post h3 a,.post h3 a:visited,.post h3 strong`. Nothing happened, And the other lines of codes I also tried to modify it to see if there is changes. The part of the codes for post section of the HTML file were I played around  is shown below. I really appreciate if anyone of you can help me on this. BTW, I'm beginner on HTML. Thanks!

```
.post {
margin:0 0 25px;
}

.post h3 a,.post h3 a:visited,.post h3 strong {
display:block;
color:#333333;
font-family:Cuprum, arial, serif;
font-size:30px;
line-height:1.3;
text-decoration:none;
}

.post h3 strong,.post h3 a:hover {
color:#333333;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [Home Page](http://alstat.blogspot.com/) your post tilte is in "a" tag which has font-size:30 
while in your detail page title is not in "a" tag.

Furthermore your css classes of title (i.e. post-title and entry-title) is not defined or you didnt link those files properly.

**Solution**:

- Try to link the file. If it exist.
- or give a new css class which have the property font-size:30

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are two classes being applied to your title:
"post-title" and "entry-title"

Try inspecting and changing those and see what comes up :)

I also recommend if you are beginner using Google Chrome's Inspect Element for finding errors and for seeing what styles are being applied to what sections

Comment: Ok I'll check that, and I will try it on Chrome. I'm using firefox actually which I happen to Inspect Elements on the post title too.

Comment: Yeah or Firefox, I just prefer chrome haha :)

Answer (score 1):

go to->Template-> edit html-> tick on Expand Widget templates-> Ctrl+F search for .post h3{ or .post h3 {       ,..... This is only one time in the overall blog code. And edit the font size at that line.